# Tfs Cmdlet Pulling Too Many Items

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am working on a PowerShell script to automate some post-build activities.  Namely, part of the release requires a list of SQL files be generated so the DBA can compile release scripts.

My script works, except it is pulling too many files.  When I specify a changeset, it is pulling back files from several other changesets.  In the Team Project I am testing in, it pulls back *all* SQL files (all five of them), but I only want the SQL files actually associated with the provided ChangesetId.

Here is my script.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how to make it pull only files from the particular changeset?

```
# Loads Windows PowerShell snap-in if not already loaded
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}

# Variables - CHECK EACH TIME
[string] $tfsCollectionPath = "http://validtfsurl:8080/tfs"
[string] $locationToSearch = "$/Sandbox/Database/"
[string] $outputFileDir = "C:\TFSTest\"
[string] $outputFileName = $outputFileDir + "ChangedSQLFiles.txt"
[string] $changeset = "C111"

 if (-not [IO.Directory]::Exists($outputFileDir))
 {
    [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($outputFileDir) | Out-Null
 }

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver $tfsCollectionPath

# Add informational header to file manifest
[string] $outputHeader =
    "TFS Collection: " + $tfsCollectionPath + "`r`n" + 
    "Source Location: " + $locationToSearch + "`r`n" + 
    "Changeset: " + $changeset + "`r`n" +
    "Created: " + (Get-Date).ToString() + "`r`n" +
    "======================================================================" 
$outputHeader | Out-File $outputFileName -Append

$items = Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch -Server $tfs -Version $changeset -Recurse -IncludeItems | 
Select-Object -Expand "Changes" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Delete*'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Rename*'} | 
    Where-Object { ($_.ChangeType -like '*Edit*') `
        -or ($_.ChangeType -like '*Add*')} |  
Select-Object -Expand "Item" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ContentLength -gt 0} |  
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -like '*.sql' } |
Select-TfsItem |
Sort -Unique Path

foreach($item in $items)
{
    [string] $ItemPath_Local = $item.Path.Trim()
    [int] $ItemPath_Length = $ItemPath_Local.Length - 19

    $ItemPath_Local = $ItemPath_Local.Replace("/", "\")
    $ItemPath_Local = $outputFileDir + "SqlFiles\" + $ItemPath_Local.Substring(19, $ItemPath_Length)

    Get-TfsChildItem $item.Path -Server $tfs -Version $changeset |
    %{$_.DownloadFile(@(join-path $outputFileDir (split-path $_.ServerItem -leaf)))}

    $item.Path.Trim() | Out-File $outputFileName -Append
}   

[string] $outputFooter = "======================================================================" 
$outputFooter | Out-File $outputFileName -Append
```

Comment: Have you thought about using something like SSDT to manage your database schema? Change scripts are an awful, painful, error-prone way to manage databases.

Comment: Yes, and we are working on using a database project for deployment to Dev databases, but the DBA will never allow for such things in test or production. Unless there is a way to use SSDT to produce such a list of files that is easier than PowerShell.

Comment: There is a DBA who's days are numbered. This is an engineering issue, not an administrative one.

Comment: @MrHinsh Perhaps, perhaps not.  This DBA has been with the company for almost 20 years.  In the meantime, the team lead spends a ton of time still on builds because we need a folder with all of our changes and we are limited on what we are allowed to do.  We are working on changing it, but it will take time.  In the meantime, we are speeding up our release cycles by adopting an agile process, and any time we can save here will only serve to highlight bottlenecks elsewhere.

Comment: Good luck @Dave , as you move towards agility and continuous delivery the dba will become a bigger bottleneck. CD is impossible unless you automate all the way to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When researching something else I found [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=VS.100).aspx) describing the syntax for the Merge command (albeit for an older TFS version) and I noticed that they were using

```
C1~C1
```

to get a single changeset.  I changed my script declarations to

```
# Variables - CHECK EACH TIME
[string] $tfsCollectionPath = "http://validtfsurl:8080/tfs"
[string] $locationToSearch = "$/Sandbox/Database/"
[string] $outputFileDir = "C:\TFSTest\"
[string] $outputFileName = $outputFileDir + "ChangedSQLFiles.txt"
[string] $changeset = "C111"
[string] $changesetRange = "C111~C111"
```

And then I changed the Get-TfsItemHistory call to

```
$items = Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch -Server $tfs -Version $changesetRange -Recurse -IncludeItems | 
Select-Object -Expand "Changes" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Delete*'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Rename*'} | 
    Where-Object { ($_.ChangeType -like '*Edit*') `
        -or ($_.ChangeType -like '*Add*')} |  
Select-Object -Expand "Item" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ContentLength -gt 0} |  
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -like '*.sql' } |
Select-TfsItem |
Sort -Unique Path
```

And finally, use only the single changeset to perform the download

```
Get-TfsChildItem $item.Path -Server $tfs -Version $changeset |
%{$_.DownloadFile(@(join-path $outputFileDir (split-path $_.ServerItem -leaf)))}
```

And that worked.  In my final code I will actually be using the TFS Environment variable to get the changeset, but the execution is the same.